# Find and display nearest date in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and I'm not sure where to start with this. I have a model for users, and one for projects. Users have many projects, and projects have one user. There is an end_date column in the projects table (as well as a name column).

What I want to do is find the project with the nearest end_date and display it's name and end date on the user's show page.

I tried putting this code in the projects controller, but I do not know if it is working, because I don't know how to access it and display the project name in the view.

```
def next_deadline(after = DateTime.now, limit = 1)
   find(:all, :conditions => ['end_date > ?', after], :limit => limit)
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Dan mentioned, you do need the `:order` clause to get the first one, but you should add it to your query and not replace the `:conditions` (otherwise you'll get the project with the earliest `end_date` irrespective of your `after` argument). The way you're defining this method is a bit off though. It should be defined in your `Project` model (and definitely **not** the controller) as a class method, or, what I think is a better approach, as a scope. In Rails < 3 (which it seems that you're using):

```rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :next_deadline, Proc.new { |after = DateTime.now, limit = 1| {:conditions => ['end_date > ?', after], :order => "end_date ASC", :limit => limit} }
  ...
end
```

Or in Rails >= 3:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :next_deadline, Proc.new { |after = DateTime.now, limit = 1| where('end_date > ?', after).order("end_date ASC").limit(limit) }
  ...
end
```

Also, you can always test this kind of code using the Rails console: `script/console` in Rails < 3, `rails c` in Rails >= 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
@projects = Project.find_by_sql("SELECT projects.* FROM projects
  JOIN users ON users.id = projects.user_id AND projects.user_id = " + @user.id.to_s + "
  WHERE projects.end_date > now()
  ORDER BY projects.end_date ASC
  LIMIT " + limit)
```

or

```
@projects = Project.where(:user_id => @user.id)
                   .where("end_date > ?", DateTime.now)
                   .order("end_date ASC")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use :order, not :conditions.

```
   Model.find(:all , :order => "end_date ASC")
```

Then the first result will be the item with the closest end_date

Answer (score 0):

As Dan said, the condition you wrote won't get the nearest end date, but the dates that are greater than today, or the date passed in as a parameter.

In your User model you could write

```
def next_deadline_project
   self.projects.first
end
```

as long as you give projects a default scope that orders records by end_date

In order to show information on the view you must set it in an instance variable in the User's controller show method. Instance variables are passed to views and you can access them to display the data.

```
@project = next_deadline_project
```

And in your show.html.erb you can use something like:

```
<%= @project.name %> - <%= @project.end_date %>
```